# Using expect.any(Object) does not match CancelToken in Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, jestjs

I recently converted a few files in a project to TypeScript and the following test started to fail:

```js
expect(mocks.request).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'bar' },
  method: 'put',
  params: file.slice(),
  path: 'foo',
  responseType: 'text',
  cancelToken: expect.any(Object),
});
```

This is the error message:

```
  expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    - Expected
    + Received

      Object {
    -   "cancelToken": Any<Object>,
    +   "cancelToken": CancelToken {
    +     "promise": Promise {},
    +   },
        "headers": Object {
          "Content-Type": "bar",
```

This is the piece of code that is tested in this case:

```js
this.cancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source();

return request({
  method: 'put',
  path: presignedUrl,
  params: file.slice(),
  cancelToken: this.cancelToken.token,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': contentType,
  },
});
```

I tried to change the test to use `expect.anything()`, like this:

```js
cancelToken: expect.anything(),
```

But I got another error:

```
    - Expected
    + Received

      Object {
    -   "cancelToken": Anything,
    +   "cancelToken": CancelToken {
    +     "promise": Promise {},
    +   },
```

How can I fix my test code?

Note: I added a `console.log(this.cancelToken.token)` to compare the value that is passed to the function `request` in the main branch and in the new branch and they are the same. So I don't know why Jest has failed this way

Comment: Where does `responseType: 'text',` come from? Remove it

Comment: nice, it worked! This line was also removed in this conversion to Typescript but I didn't realize that it was the problem, because the error message was not clear about it!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my test was wrong, when I removed the line `responseType: 'text',` it worked!